# Tcl: Is there a more efficient way to retrieve a nested value in a dictionary that was converted from JSON?

Tags: json, dictionary, tcl

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to retrieve the 'id' value 7777777 paired with the entry key. I am using the Tcllib json package.

```
package require json

set json {
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "11111111-22222-3cc3-4444-d5d555dd5555",
    "type": "searchset",
    "total": 1,
    "link": [
        {
            "relation": "self",
            "url": "https://selfurl.com/a54"
        }
    ],
    "entry": [
        {
            "fullUrl": "https://test.sandboxtest.com/e2/1a11aaa1-22bb-3333-4444dd-e5e5ee55ee55/Patient/lastname=test",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Patient",
                "id": "7777777",
                "meta": {
                    "versionId": "5",
                    "lastUpdated": "2020-10-08T18:26:31.000Z"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}

set jsDict [json::json2dict $json]
set entryVal [dict get $jsDict entry]

if {[regexp {Patient id ([^ ]+)} $entryVal match idVal]} {
    puts $idVal
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use list operations for JSON arrays. So something like this:

```
puts [dict get [lindex [dict get $jsDict entry] 0] resource id]
```

Alternatively you can extract the data from `$json` directly with rl_json:

```
puts [rl_json::json get $json entry 0 resource id]
```

Comment: The `rl_json` package is strongly encouraged. It works very well even with _big_ JSON documents, and is designed to be fast. The only downside, and then only in some environments, is that it is written in C and not pure Tcl. That's not a showstopper for most deployments, but occasionally someone has weird rules on that sort of thing.